# Python arrays/lists: convert total to relative values

Tags: python, arrays, list, converters

I'm looking for the most simple way to get the total values of arr_A listed as relative values in arr_B.

I want to avoid using a loop like `value[i]/sum(arr_A)`

Note: arr_A is dynamically changing, this is just a simple example

**Is there a simple build in function?**

```
arr_A = [2, 4, 2, 2]

#do magic

arr_B = [0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2]
```

Comment: What do you mean 'dynamically changing'? It looks like `arr_B` is just supposed to contain the result.

Comment: yep, sorry, I meant arr_A is changing -> change it

Comment: Still, what do you mean by that? You realize that if it changes you will have to update `arr_B` as well?

Comment: This tiny piece of code is nested somewhere deep inside my code. arr_A does not exist, it is generated programmatically like a thousand times and will look different every single time. for every arr_A I have to generate an arr_B with the relative values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the built-in function `map` with a lambda function

```
arr_B = list(map(lambda x: x/sum(arr_A), arr_A))
```

Comment: This will sum `arr_A` for each element. Not very efficient

Comment: @Tomerikoo you can assign the value of `sum(arr_A)` to a variable when efficiency is a concern. But for a list of size of 5, it will make less than 1ms of difference in terms of runtime on any modern computer.

Comment: The prevailing view is that comprehensions should be preferred over the functional idioms such as filter and map. Shorter and more Pythonic.

Comment: @JussiNurminen I don't disagree with your statement, but the OP specifically said that they were looking for a built-in function.

Comment: @pkqxdd I don't think OP cares about whether or not it's technically a function, just that it's built-in.

Answer (score 2):

Pure Python:

```
s = sum(arr_A)
arr_B = [x/s for x in arr_B]
```

However for numerical operations, the numpy library is your friend. In numpy, this can be written:

```
arr_B = np.array(arr_A) / np.sum(arr_A)
```